# Excluding last element in 0-based indexing

Tags: python, arrays, programming-languages

Once when I was reading some python docs I came across a reference to an article that explained why programming languages with 0-based indexing should always exclude the last element during operations like slicing:

```
>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>> a[0:1]
[1]  #and not [1,2]
```

Unfortunately I did not bookmark it. Does anyone know which article I am talking about?

PS: I welcome any explanations of why this is for my immediate satisfaction :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could it be [this note](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/ewd08xx/EWD831.PDF) from E. W. Dijkstra?

Comment: Just read it - yes that article is great :-) Love the way he derives it by exclusion.

Answer (score 5):

No, but there are at least two good reasons:

1. `a[m:n]` gives you *n*-*m* elements, making it easy to compute how many elements you are requesting.
2. With inclusive end-points, it's awkward to request an empty slice (`a[3:2]`? yuck).

**Edit:** I just thought of another Python-specific reason: a[m:-n] excludes the first *m* and last *n* items. If it was inclusive, it would exclude the first *m* and last *n*-1 items, which is much harder to remember.

Comment: Another reason: a[m:n] + a[n:p] = a[m:p]

Answer (score 3):

You might be thinking of [Dijkstra's short note about zero-based numbering](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200909/why_numbering_should_start_at_zero.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly which article you are referring to, but Googling [half-open ranges](http://www.google.com/search?q=half-open+ranges) should find it for you.  It found [this surprisingly good one](http://www.siliconbrain.com/ranges.htm) that I think is a new personal favorite.

Comment: 'Tis a pity that it is not an editable article; the content is good, but the presentation is sloppy with lots of idiosyncratic typos.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the first extensive treatment in print was in Koenig's great book, [C Traps and Pitfalls](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201179288) -- 20 years old and still in print (indeed, in-stock and shipped immediately from Amazon!-), quite a tribute to its nature as a classic.  Unfortunately, there are no previews of it available in Google Books, and while the PDF of the internal report which formed the book *is* available [online](http://www.literateprogramming.com/ctraps.pdf), it's obviously much shorter than the book and in particular it does not mention the "open-ranges" issue.  There are of course pirate copies on the web, but I don't recommend downloading those.

Several years ago, I summarized Koenig's reasoning [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/msg/1bf4d925dfbf368?pli=1), with a followup discussion [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2001-May/682787.html), but of course that's no substitute for the complete treatment as found in his book (though it may be a helpful complement, as in the second post in particular I add other observations in response to critique that was posted on that thread).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know any specific article, but I think the rationale is simply that this way you get the number of resulting elements via simple subtraction, 1-0=1, instead of having to add 1 there (which you would forget half of the time anyway).

Comment: Thanks but I was really hoping to read the article. For some strange reason I just feel like reading a treatise on this topic!!! o-x